# An error IOExceptionERROR: parse error - invalid geometry Hint: “POLYGON ((” <— parse error at position 12 within geometry

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, geometry, rendering

I'm a beginner in GeoServer. I moved a layer using the PostGIS (version 3.0.1) module in QGIS (version 3.12.1-București) to the PostgreSQL 12 database without problems and it looks good in pgAdmin 4.

I did the steps of adding a layer to GeoServer (Version 2.16.2), but at the end there's an error displaying on layer preview:

[image]

geoserver log:

```
dImageMapOutputFormat.java:133)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:707)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:287)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:110)
        at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.ja
va:253)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ
e Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native
MethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(De
legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflecti
on(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJo
inpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKml
Interceptor.java:38)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWe
bMapService.java:55)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWe
bMapService.java:31)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapServic
e.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapServic
e.java:53)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger
.java:50)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynami
cAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.getMap(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ
e Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native
MethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(De
legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:879)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:26
5)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(
AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.ha
ndle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl
et.java:890)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873
)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1623)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocals
CleanupFilter.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDel
egatingFilter.java:69)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java
:73)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDel
egatingFilter.java:66)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatin
gFilter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispat
chFilter.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter
ceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter
ceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.do
Filter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.
doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticati
onFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFi
lter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFi
lter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilt
er$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(Fi
lterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChai
nProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(Geo
ServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(D
elegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Delegat
ingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilte
r.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.
java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:4
2)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1610)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern
al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java
:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
a:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper
.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandl
er.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl
er.java:1700)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandl
er.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl
er.java:1345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandle
r.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:
480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle
r.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandle
r.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle
r.java:1247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont
extHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerColl
ection.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper
.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.jav
a:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(Abstra
ctConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhat
YouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWh
atYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatW
hatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouK
ill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.r
un(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo
l.java:698)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThrea
dPool.java:804)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeat
ureCollection.java:165)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeat
ureCollection.java:52)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRende
rer.java:2603)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(Streaming
Renderer.java:2189)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.
java:890)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(Rendere
dImageMapOutputFormat.java:594)
        ... 128 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSour
ce.java:625)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureStore.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureStore
.java:217)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeature
Source.java:609)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeat
ureCollection.java:163)
        ... 133 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: pars
e error - invalid geometry
  Hint: "POLYGON ((?" <-- parse error at position 12 within geometry
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.runQuery(JDBCFeatureReader.java:2
63)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.<init>(JDBCFeatureReader.java:143
)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSour
ce.java:595)
        ... 136 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: parse error - invalid geome
try
  Hint: "POLYGON ((?" <-- parse error at position 12 within geometry
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryEx
ecutorImpl.java:2440)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutor
Impl.java:2183)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.ja
va:308)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)

        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307
)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293
)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270
)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:224)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingSt
atement.java:208)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingSt
atement.java:208)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.lambda$new$0(JDBCFeatureReader.ja
va:143)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.runQuery(JDBCFeatureReader.java:2
52)
        ... 138 more
```

and Full URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/myworkspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=myworkspace%3Awaterways_IRN&bbox=44.0108642578125%2C25.0663452148438%2C63.5713768005371%2C39.9720458984375&width=768&height=585&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=application/openlayers
```